# Link Each Record To All Other Records With Incremental Number

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL Server 2008R2 table that has some user names.  I need to create an association between each user and every other user and I'm not sure how to do this with joins.  As an additional wrinkle, I need to get an incremental unique ID as well.  For example, I have this data:

```
user_a    User Name A
user_b    User Name B
user_c    User Name C
```

I want to run a query and get something like the following:

```
1    user_a    user_a
2    user_a    user_b
3    user_a    user_c
4    user_b    user_a
5    user_b    user_b
6    user_b    user_c
7    user_c    user_a
etc...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `CROSS JOIN` and `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.col1, B.col1) UniqueID,
        A.col1,
        B.col1
FROM dbo.YourTable A
CROSS JOIN dbo.YourTable B
ORDER BY A.col1, B.col1
```

Comment: Awesome!  Works great, thanks...  I'll accept this as the answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second "lookup table" user_assoc with three columns id, user_id, user_assoc_id.

This example:

```
1    user_a    user_a
2    user_a    user_b
3    user_a    user_c
4    user_b    user_a
5    user_b    user_b
6    user_b    user_c
7    user_c    user_a
etc...
```

would turn into:

```
1 1 1
2 1 2
3 1 3
4 2 1
5 2 2
6 2 3
7 3 1 
8 3 2
9 3 3
```

you could then run a SQL join on your users table on user_id

Comment: Thanks but I would still need to use the query that @Lamak showed below to create the second table and with that query there's no real need for the additional table.